# Easy way to toggle between 2 volume levels

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, audio

I'm looking for a simple way to toggle between 50% and 100% of system volume level in Windows 7.

Over the day I run at 100% and later I change volume to 50%.. Well it's 2 clicks.. Not a big deal, but I'm lazy and looking for some commandline script or something else to toggle my volume between those 2 levels.
I know it's easily done with a few lines of c code, and there are probably many applications out there providing this feature, but I'm looking for a clean and native way to do this.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend [Nircmd by Nirsoft](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html).

You can set the volume via the following command:

```
nircmd.exe setsysvolume x
```

Where `x` is a value between `0` and `65535`, so 50% would be `32767`.

You can create a shortcut anywhere on your system, then set a keyboard shortcut to run this command - technically it would still be two buttons you have to do, but I hope this will be more convenient to you.

Comment: not exactly what I'm looking for, but I'll give it a try, thx